# Number of sequences of length $N$ with an increasing subsequence of length $K$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $N$ distinct numbers, the number of ways of arranging them so as to get a length $N$ sequence is $N!$. I want to know how many of these $N!$ sequences have an increasing subsequence of length $K < N$ (at least one such subsequence).

Comment: if $N=4$ and $K=3$ does this count?:  $4,1,2,3$.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: Did you mean "Given a positive integer $K<N$, I want to know [...]" ?

Comment: yes, K and N are given.

Comment: Maybe you can study easy cases as $K = N$ or $K = N - 1$.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want but it is related and interesting http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-04/S0894-0347-99-00307-0/S0894-0347-99-00307-0.pdf